# Windows 10 thinks my controller is always inputting "up"

Tags: windows-10, game-controller

So I had an old Xbox controller which had some major stick drift issues. Occasionally after exiting a game, Windows would think I was pushing up on the stick or d-pad in the Start Menu or other "UWP" apps (such as settings or the store). This means I cannot click on any application, nor can I even click on the Power options to restart the computer. I've tried unplugging and replugging the controller and trying to give it inputs, but it immediately goes and tries to select the upmost button. I also bought a new controller, which does not have any stick drift whatsoever, the issue persists.

Is there a way I can fix this, or just permanently tell windows not to accept Xbox input outside of games?

Comment: I have experienced this as well. You can disconnect the controller after playing your game. Sometimes it persists after disconnecting, but is usually resolved by reconnecting and disconnecting again.

Comment: @MichaelZ. As I said in the question, no amount of disconnecting and reconnecting works. Windows is stuck like that until the next restart.

Comment: That's why I said it usually works (for me anyway). Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the controller in Windows Settings. Go to Settings->Devices and remove from there. Then add it again. Worth a shot if you haven't tried that.

Comment: I think I know how this happens - I think it's game related. Make sure to disconnect the controller before leaving the game. I recall a few times where I had to start the game up just to disconnect the controller while in game. That seemed to work for me.

Comment: I should point out that my actual issue was the mouse cursor drifting but was related to the controller joystick sticking exactly as you're describing. I never had to restart my computer to resolve.

Comment: @MichaelZ. I've tried removing and adding the device and it still glitches out. I've even unplugged the control before exiting the game and Windows was spazzing our really badly. I don't know how you don't have to force restart, I have no way of telling the computer to restart because the power menu was flashing rapidly and wouldn't accept any input. This last restart has led to corrupted Steam files. I'm getting very tired of this.